# JNI cannot detect __int64 on NetBeans

Tags: java, c++, c, netbeans, java-native-interface

I'm trying to compile a native library to use it from java (with JNI). I have followed this tutorial:
https://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html

## The error

When I try to compile, I have this error (see line 4):

```
[...]
In file included from ../../Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include/jni.h:45:0,
                 from HelloWorldNative.h:3,
                 from HelloWorldNative.c:6:
../../Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include/win32/jni_md.h:34:9: error: unknown type name '__int64'
 typedef __int64 jlong;
         ^
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/HelloWorldNative.o' failed
[...]
```

I can solve this error adding a `typedef long long __int64` before the `#include <jni.h>` but I assume that there is something that I'm doing wrong.

## The code

Here is the code:

HEADER FILE:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
typedef long long __int64; // <============ Why do I need to do this?
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class helloworld_Main */

#ifndef _Included_helloworld_Main
#define _Included_helloworld_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     helloworld_Main
 * Method:    nativePrint
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloworld_Main_nativePrint
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

SOURCE FILE:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
#include "HelloWorldNative.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloworld_Main_nativePrint
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject _this){

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__int64` is Visual Studio [specific type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/29dh1w7z.aspx)

Use standard types like [int64_t or uint64_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Defined in `<cstdint>` for C++  and in `<stdint.h>` for C.

---

Exact solution to your error can be found in JNI faq:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jni-j2sdk-faq-141732.html

```
Your compiler might not like __int64 in jni_md.h. You should fix this by adding:
    #ifdef FOOBAR_COMPILER
    #define __int64 signed_64_bit_type
    #endif
where signed_64_bit_type is the name of the signed 64 bit type supported by your compiler.
```

so you should use:

```
#define __int64 long long
```

or:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define __int64 int64_t
```

which is quite similar to what you have initially done

Comment: I have tried to add a `#include <stdint.h>` before the `#include <jni.h>`, but it does not work.

Comment: @Dan see my edit, actualy what you have done initially would be acceptable solution - at least oracle suggest doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First check your c compiler in the build tools. Changing that fixed the error for me.

[image: Screenshot]