# Netbeans JNI __int64 missing - caused by jni_md.h:34:9

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, java-native-interface

I can't get the JNI sample by Netbeans to work.

> gcc -shared -m32   -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/JNIDemo.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/JNIDemo.o JNIDemo.c
>
> In file included from /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/jni.h:45:0,
>                    from JNIDemoJava.h:6,
>                    from JNIDemo.c:2:
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/win32/jni_md.h:34:9: error: unknown type name '__int64'
>    typedef __int64 jlong;
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```

```
#ifndef _Included_jnidemojava_Main
    #define _Included_jnidemojava_Main
    #include <jni.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
    #endif
            /*
             * Class:     jnidemojava_Main
             * Method:    nativePrint
             * Signature: ()V
             */
            JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint
            (JNIEnv *, jobject);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
        }
    #endif


    #ifndef __int64
        #define __int64 signed_64_bit_type long long
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JNI cannot detect \_\_int64 on NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846746/jni-cannot-detect-int64-on-netbeans)

Comment: Well, that solution worked for the other guy but not me.

Comment: And why is that? Then please wrote the things which you already tried.

Comment: What I tried has already been written/pasted, including the header file. So what else do you need? It does not change the fact that I'm still getting this.

Comment: Do you *really* have `#define __int64 signed_64_bit_type long long` in your code?

Comment: What @Andrew said. And does it get defined _before_ including the header file?